# How to change the colour of a scrollbar on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can somebody tell me how to change the colour of a scrollbar on a web page?

Comment: Either can be used to change scroll bar style

Comment: That depends on browsers. You can do with webkit, such as Chrome, Opera. But you cannot do with IE, Firefox by only CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 1em;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: red;
outline: 1px solid darkgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You May Use [SlimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll). It also helps more features than adding color.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rocha.la/misc/jsdemos/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#id_of_div_you_need_scroll').slimScroll({
        width: '300px',
        height: '200px',
        color: '#ffcc00',
        /* size: '10px',
         position: 'left',
         alwaysVisible: true,
         distance: '20px',
         start: $('#child_image_element'),
         railVisible: true,
         railColor: '#222',
         railOpacity: 0.3,
         wheelStep: 10,
         allowPageScroll: false,
         disableFadeOut: false*/
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
          if (!$.browser.webkit) {
              $('.wrapper').html('<p>Sorry! Non webkit users. :(</p>');
          }
      });
```

```css
header
{
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px; 
}

#info
{
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #555;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

a{
 color: #074E8C;
}

.scrollbar
{
 margin-left: 30px;
 float: left;
 height: 300px;
 width: 65px;
 background: #F5F5F5;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.force-overflow
{
 min-height: 450px;
}

#wrapper
{
 text-align: center;
 width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 1
 */

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: #555;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 2
 */

#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: #D62929;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 3
 */

#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 6px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #000000;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 4
 */

#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #000000;
 border: 2px solid #555555;
}


/*
 *  STYLE 5
 */

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #0ae;
 
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,
                    color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)),
        color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
}


/*
 *  STYLE 6
 */

#style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-6::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #F90; 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,
                                           rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
             transparent 25%,
             transparent 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
             transparent 75%,
             transparent)
}


/*
 *  STYLE 7
 */

#style-7::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-7::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-7::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
            left bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0.44, rgb(122,153,217)),
            color-stop(0.72, rgb(73,125,189)),
            color-stop(0.86, rgb(28,58,148)));
}

/*
 *  STYLE 8
 */

#style-8::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-8::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-8::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #000000; 
}


/*
 *  STYLE 9
 */

#style-9::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-9::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-9::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #F90; 
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                           rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
             transparent 25%,
             transparent 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
             transparent 75%,
             transparent)
}


/*
 *  STYLE 10
 */

#style-10::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-10::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-10::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #AAA;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                           rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 25%,
             transparent 25%,
             transparent 50%,
             rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 50%,
             rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 75%,
             transparent 75%,
             transparent)
}


/*
 *  STYLE 11
 */

#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #3366FF;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,
                                           rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 25%,
             transparent 25%,
             transparent 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 75%,
             transparent 75%,
             transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 12
 */

#style-12::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #444444;
}

#style-12::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-12::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #D62929;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
             transparent,
             rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 50%,
             transparent,
             transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 13
 */

#style-13::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#style-13::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-13::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #D62929;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
             transparent,
             rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 50%,
             transparent,
             transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 14
 */

#style-14::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#style-14::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-14::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #FFF;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                           rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
             rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 25%,
             transparent 100%,
             rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 75%,
             transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 15
 */

#style-15::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-15::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-15::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
            40% 0%,
            75% 84%,
            from(#4D9C41),
            to(#19911D),
            color-stop(.6,#54DE5D))
}

/*
 *  STYLE 16
 */

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,
             #e4f5fc 0%,
             #bfe8f9 50%,
             #9fd8ef 51%,
             #2ab0ed 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbar" id="style-default">
  <div class="force-overflow"></div>
   </div>

<div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">
  <div class="force-overflow"></div>
</div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-2">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-3">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-4">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-5">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-6">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-7">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-8">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-9">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-10">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-11">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-13">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-14">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-15">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing scrollbar colour is a bit tricky. You can do it using the specific CSS rules, but it's going to be very dependent on the browser you are using.

To solve this, there are plenty of JavaScript plugins that hidde the original scrollbar and set a new one made by html elements, which is fully customizable. You can review [this](https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/), for example.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am really new, like I started a couple months ago

Comment: I'm glad I helped